# How to get YouTube Likes playlist by YouTube API?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, youtube-api

I have tried this:

```
    Feed<Playlist> userPlaylists = request.GetPlaylistsFeed(username);
foreach (Playlist p in userPlaylists.Entries)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Title: " + p.Title);
  Console.WriteLine(p.Summary);
  Console.WriteLine("Number of entries: " + p.CountHint);
}
```

it can't read "`Likes`" playlist.

Google Document have provider "Favorites", "History" and "customized playlist".
Not provider API of Get `Likes` playlist.

Does anyone have idea to get `Likes` playlist?

Thank You.